# ASP.NET Viewstate Optimization/Analyzing Tools

Tags: asp.net

Are there any tools for analyzing the controls in an ASP.NET page, to make sure they do not need to use the viewstate?

We are trying to optimize a website written in C# asp.net 3.5 , and wanted to see if a tool would automatically analyze the project and make recommendations.

Comment: You could just turn off viewstate for all your controls and turn stuff back on until its no longer broken

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with tools specifically for analyzing the ViewState of different elements on an asp.net page.

I almost never save ViewState of table elements like DataGrid or GridView, since these element have HUGE ViewState objects that aren't neede most of the time. You need to think logically which element's state you need to save for the user.

You can also enable 'Trace' ([Enabling Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)), proxy sniffer tools like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and different performance add-ons (like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for FireFox) to see how much data you're sending to the server on each call and how much you're getting back, where the time is being taken up mostly, and try to see which data isn't necessary.

A good article on improving performance of an asp.net web application : http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article45.aspx

Comment: correct me if im wrong but if you disable the viewstate of a GridView then your buttons will stop working (if you have any in it)?

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of is a FireFox extension called [Viewstate size](http://www.kirkov.dk/projects/firefox/viewstatesize), which displays the size of the viewstate in the bottom status bar in the browser.  You can see the size on the unmodified page, make some code changes and refresh the browser to see if your changes made any difference in the viewstate size.